# issue with reference to .dll

Tags: c#, dll, reference, sevenzipsharp, typeinitializeexception

currently making a small program by using WinForms and 7zip unpacker. To make it easier added reference to "SevenZipSharp.dll" everything work good, untill i wanted to publish(debug) project. When i move the ".exe" file in Desktop got error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
>   assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies".

I embedded resource set in .dll file + Copy Local: set to true

How i can make this programs to work without .dll in Current directory.

**EDIT**

I did it by use

> System.Reflections

[Solution here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KK7bmo1AM)

But i got now another problem with

```
     System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager' threw an exception.. ---> System.ArgumentException:  Path has an illegal format
   w System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   w System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   w System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   w System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
   w SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   w SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager.SetLibraryPath(String libraryPath)
   w SevenZip.SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(String libraryPath)
```

Comment: not an expert on this but i think it has to be

Comment: What u mean exactly ? Its not impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to have the referenced libraries in the same folder or else you can also register them in GAC.

Comment: I try it in Main project folder, \bin folder , and \Debug\bin folder... and nothing

Comment: Please keep .exe in same location as the referenced library (.dll)

Comment: My problem is that I want to include this .dll in .exe file

Comment: Why would you want to do so. But, you can try ILMerge (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630). Thjere would be utilities which can help.

Comment: I solved it using System.Reflection.. i got another erro *edited first post